# Extract a double from a string[] in Java?

Tags: java, string, double, extract

Note: Java

I have a String[] called moneyEntered.

moneyEntered[0] has the value "$5.00"

I wish to create a new double (called amountPendingDeduction) which extracts the value "5.00" from moneyEntered[0] (i.e. removing the dollar sign and making the rest a double).

How do I do this?

Comment: remove the `$` sign and use `Double.parseDouble(String)`. Note, doubles or floating point primitives arent the best option if you want to represent currencies.

Comment: @kevinEsche Is there a way to do it without removing the dollar sign? The string moneyEntered itself is inputted by the user, and they will input "$5.00".
Also, what is the best to use for currency? BigDecimal?

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769669/convert-string-to-double-in-java

Comment: @dearv i think there´s no way around it. Yes `BigDecimal` is a better option. You wont have to deal with precision loss here.

Comment: Check this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23990805/converting-different-countrys-currency-to-double-using-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with currency, double is just fine:

```
String money = moneyEntered[0].substring(1);
double moneyValue = Double.parseDouble(money);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Double amountPendingDeduction = Double.parseDouble(moneyEntered[0].replace("\\$", ""));
```

Since String is immutable, nothing will happen with the dollar sign in the moneyEntered[0] string.