# Parsing currency to double raising exception

Tags: java, android, parsing, currency

I have a string which is "R$3.333,33" and I'm trying to parse it to a double value with this method:

```
public static BigDecimal parse(final String amount, final Locale locale) throws ParseException {
        final NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
        if (format instanceof DecimalFormat) {
            ((DecimalFormat) format).setParseBigDecimal(true);
        }
        return (BigDecimal) format.parse(amount.replaceAll("[^\\d.,]", ""));
    }
```

But I'm getting an exception that says:

```
W/System.err: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "3.333,33" (at offset 8)
```

And I'm using it like:

```
Ferramentas.parse(value.getText().toString(), Locale.FRANCE)
```

Comment: Which Locale you're using?

Comment: @m0skit0 I'm Using Locale.FRANCE

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting different countrys currency to double using java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23990805/converting-different-countrys-currency-to-double-using-java)

Comment: @MarceloVinícius That answer doesn't work for `.` for thousands, it prints `3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I found is to replace `.` in your regex as well:

```
return (BigDecimal) format.parse(amount.replaceAll("[^\\d,]",""));
```

I haven't been able to parse a number with a `.` for thousands.

- If you keep the `.` it gets parsed to `3`.
- If you replace the `.` by `,`, it gets parsed to `3.333`.

If anyone has a solution for the `.` for thousands, I would be really interested in hearing it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23990805/converting-different-countrys-currency-to-double-using-java).

Although it looks like a duplicate, the `parse` method works if your input is "R$ 3.333,33" (notice the space between the currency symbol and the value).

To insert a space between the currency symbol and the value, you can use a method like this:

```
public static String insertSpaceBetweenSymbolAndValue(String s)
{
    int index = 0;
    while (index < s.length() && !Character.isDigit(s.charAt(index)))
        index++;
    return (index != s.length()) ? s.substring(0, index) + " " + s.substring(index) : s;
}
```

Comment: how can I put that space between the value and the symbol?

Comment: @AND4011002849 Edited my answer to include such method.

Comment: Everything works fine from that answer until you add `.` for thousands.

Comment: Are you keeping the `replaceAll()`?

Comment: In fact, if I keep the `replaceAll()`, it does not get parsed.

Comment: If I remove the `replaceAll`, it does throw an exception `ParseException: Unparseable number: "$199.00"`.

Comment: And btw the answer you link to does use replaceAll. Can you please just post the code you're using?

Answer (score -2):

Why not you remove 'R$ ', then parse your double?

```
String s = b.substring(3, b.length()); 
Double d = Double.valueOf(s);
```

Comment: He's already removing R$: `amount.replaceAll("[^\\d.,]", "")`.