# Getting data from table using Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a table of fees I am trying to parse through to return data, but it is returning a few blanks before it actually returning the string of data.

```
<table id="Fees">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Rate Code</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="code">A1</td>
                        <td>Charge Type 1</td>
                        <td class="amount">$11.20</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="code">C2</td>
                        <td>Charge Type 2</td>
                        <td class="amount">$36.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="code">CMI</td>
                        <td>Cuba Medical Insurance</td>
                        <td class="amount">$25.00</td>
                    </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">Total:</td>
                    <td class="amount">$145.16</td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
</table>
```

I return by xpath

```
private By lst_Fee
{
    get { return By.XPath("//*[@id=\"Fees\"]/tbody/tr"); }
}
```

Selenium code:

```
IList<IWebElement> fees = GetNativeElements(lst_Fee, 5);
List<string> actual = new List<string>();
foreach (IWebElement elem in fees)
{
    actual.Add(GetText(elem, ControlType.Label));
}
```

**Questions**

1. Is ControlType.Label correct for a table?  I am getting a few blank elems before actually getting to the data.
2. If I wanted to separate each Rate, Description and Fee out in each item to make sure the cost adds up to Total correctly, how can I do that?

Comment: What does `GetText()` do, and what is `GetNativeElements(By by, int num)`? I would expect you want to get just the column with your fee, instead of the entire row when you add to actual which is seems like you're doing now. There is also converting to `int`s involved, this is a pretty big question.

Comment: Do you actually want to store/use the rate and description or is getting the fee back good enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like the below. I created a class `Fee` that holds the parts of a fee: the code, description, and amount. For each table row , you would extract these three values and store them in an instance of the `Fee` class. The function returns a collection of `Fee` instances. To get the sum of the fees themselves, you would call the `GetFees()` method and then iterate through the `Fee` instances summing the `amount` into the final Total.

```
public class Fee
{
    private String code;
    private String desc;
    private BigDecimal amount;

    private Fee(String _code, String _desc, BigDecimal _amount)
    {
        this.code = _code;
        this.desc = _desc;
        this.amount = _amount;
    }
}

public List<Fee> GetFees()
{
    List<Fee> fees = new ArrayList<Fee>();
    List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#Fees > tbody > tr"));
    for (WebElement row : rows)
    {
        List<WebElement> cells = row.findElements(By.cssSelector("td"));
        fees.add(new Fee(cells.get(0).getText(), cells.get(1).getText(), parse(cells.get(2).getText(), Locale.US)));
    }

    return fees;
}

// borrowed from http://stackoverflow.com/a/23991368/2386774
public BigDecimal parse(final String amount, final Locale locale) throws ParseException
{
    final NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale);
    if (format instanceof DecimalFormat)
    {
        ((DecimalFormat) format).setParseBigDecimal(true);
    }
    return (BigDecimal) format.parse(amount.replaceAll("[^\\d.,]", ""));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can grab all the column headers and as well the row data by the below code:
Happy coding =
 //// Grab the table
            IWebElement grid;
            grid = _browserInstance.Driver.FindElement(By.Id("tblVoucherLookUp"));
            IWebElement headercolumns = grid.FindElement(By.Id("tblVoucherLookUp"));
          _browserInstance.Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(75));
            _browserInstance.ScreenCapture("Voucher LookUp Grid");

                //// get the column headers
            char[] character = "\r\n".ToCharArray();
            string[] Split = headercolumns.Text.Split(character);

            for (int i = 0; i < Split.Length; i++)
            {
                if (Split[i] != "")
                {
                    _log.LogEntry("INFO", "Voucher data", true,
                    Split + " Text matches the expected:" + Split[i]);
                }
            }
```