# Can you parse a specific index of a String Array to a double number?

Tags: java

I have an array of Strings where one index specifically the 7th one, needs to be a double number so I could use a conditional on it.

```
while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                    String customer = s.nextLine();
                    String[] fields = customer.split("\\|");

double score = Double.parseDouble(fields[7]);
}
```

Also gave this a try, but no luck. Still the same error.

```
while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                String customer = s.nextLine();
                String[] fields = customer.split("\\|");
                if (Double.parseDouble(fields[7]) > 5.00) {
```

The fields[7] contains all the numbers in my input file but how do I make them double values in order to use a conditional on them in an if statement. All the other indexes must stay at strings however.

Doing this causes this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "$280.80"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
    at CollectionLetter.main(CollectionLetter.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

SOLUTION: THE ANSWER WAS THAT I HAD CURRENCY SYMBOLS AND I WAS TRYING TO PARSE IT STILL, I SIMPLY USED:

```
            if (Double.parseDouble(fields[7].replace("$","")) > 5.00) {
```

THANK YOU EVERYONE!

Comment: [`Double#parseDouble`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String))

Comment: Double.parseDouble()

Comment: why not you use regex?

Comment: You need to remove the first character in the string - `'$'`, before using it as input.

Comment: OMG, I hadn't thought about that! Thank you so much @Gendarme

Comment: Doubles don't contain currency symbols. Remove it before you try parsing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please handle parsing currencies correctly. Although your string is "$123456.78", in other parts of the world "₹3,00,00,000" or "R$ 399,00" are valid amounts.

Use [NumberFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/numberFormat.html) to avoid things blowing up when your friend in Japan runs your code.

If you don't think all that is really needed, here is Boris' shortcut: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23991368/3430807

Comment: Yeah I am truly a fool for not thinking about the currency marks were the reasoning behind the error in parsing it as a double. You are answer is more correct than the only other one, so I give it to you.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you must be trying to check for a double value from a string.

In this case, Double.parseDouble is needed.

```
if(Double.parseDouble(fields[7]) ... )
```

Comment: I tried it but got the error that I included onto the edit of my post