# Fail in Double.parse

Tags: java

I have a error when I tried do:

```
private Double isEmpty(String some) {

    LOGGER.info("Se ha llamado a isEmpty, valor: " + some);
    Double empty = null;

    try {
        if (some != null) {
            // Reemplazar porque nosotros usamos los . para los miles
            if(some.contains(".")) {
                some = some.replaceAll(".", "");
            }
            if(some.contains(",")) {
                some = some.replaceAll(",", ".");
            }
            empty = Double.parseDouble(some);
            LOGGER.info("Nuevo valor en isEmpty en Double: " + some);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOGGER.error("*******************");
        LOGGER.error("************ Falló la ejecución isEmpty *************");
        LOGGER.error(ex.getMessage() + ex);
        LOGGER.error(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        LOGGER.error("*******************");
    }

    return empty;
}
```

In my country "1.000" this is one thousand, In America is One...
Then I replace all the characters for format in English...

For example in my country : "2.035,75€" --> Two thousands thirty five with seventy five ... I can't parse this. I do replace ->

"2035.75" for that Java admit this number. BUT I get error ->

```
 Se ha llamado a isEmpty, valor: 19.425
2018-10-16 ERROR 6197 --- [nio-8090-exec-5] Imp  : *******************
2018-10-16 ERROR 6197 --- [nio-8090-exec-5] Imp  : ************ Falló la ejecución isEmpty *************
2018-10-16 ERROR 6197 --- [nio-8090-exec-5] Imp  : empty Stringjava.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
2018-10-16  ERROR 6197 --- [nio-8090-exec-5] Imp  : empty String
2018-10-16  ERROR 6197 --- [nio-8090-exec-5] Imp  : *******************
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`replaceAll` takes a regex and `.` is the regex char that matches anything, so `some.replaceAll(".", "")` replaces everything with nothing. You would need to esapce `.`:

```
some = some.replaceAll("\\.", "");
```

or simply use `replace` insteadf, which does not take in a regex but a regular `CharSequence` or `char`:

```
some = some.replace(".", "");
```

Note that if you use an IDE you might get a highlight on the regex part, I would recommnd using one:

[image]

Comment: ... or just use [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-)

Comment: @khelwood but there may be more than one match to be replaced.

Comment: Yes, that's what replace does. "Replaces each substring of this string that matches the literal target sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence." It just doesn't use a regular expression, so you don't have to escape anything.

Comment: @khelwood you are correct, I just programmed in js and got confused, there the replace with a normal string only replaces once...

Comment: @khelwood if you have more than one decimal separator in your string, you should fail anyway - what is the expected value of "123.45.67"?

Comment: @spi In the OP's question, `.` is a thousands separator.

Comment: hi All, but the problem doesn't "." is when I use Double.parseDouble "19.425" ...

Comment: @EduBw please read my first sentence very carefully, I write "replaces everything with nothing" for a reason, what does "19.425" after everything is replaced with nothing?

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using localization for your problem. Please see  [Converting different countrys currency to double using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23990805/converting-different-countrys-currency-to-double-using-java)

**You could try the following:**

```
public BigDecimal parseMoney(String some) {
    try {
        Locale yourLocale = new Locale("es", "ES");
        return parse(some, yourLocale);
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
        return null;
    }
}

public BigDecimal parse(String amount, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
    final NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale);
    if (format instanceof DecimalFormat) {
        ((DecimalFormat) format).setParseBigDecimal(true);
    }
    return (BigDecimal) format.parse(amount);
}
```

**Please note that**

- your method `isEmpty` does not do what its name suggests so I changed it to `parseMoney`
- when dealing with money you should not rely on `Double` so I changed the return type to `BigDecimal`
- I assumed you are located in a Spanish speaking country so I chose the `Locale("es", "ES")` but make sure to adjust it as needed

Comment: Apart from the programming error this is the correct answer. But please include more content in this answer, right now it is more like a comment since basically link-only. How would OP have to change his code to do what you suggest?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I added some more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
some = some.replaceAll(".", "");
```

to

```
some = s.replaceAll("\\.", "");
```

Because `.` (dot) means matching  with all.

Answer (score 1):

`replaceAll` needs two parameter: 1st is regex and 2nd is substring which is to be replaced.

so in regex `.` has meaning of any single character, so your each and every character is replaced with null value as you code:  `some = some.replaceAll(".", "")`

try this:  `some = some.replaceAll("\\.", "")`

Answer (score -1):

I think you don't need to do replaceAll. Below code should work

```
        String some = "19.27";
        double d = Double.parseDouble(some);
        System.out.println("String " + some + " is parse to double value : " + d);
```