# How i can covert a string '$1400.00' to an int 1400.00 in Java

Tags: java

Can anyone help me to convert a string with both number and character to an integer in Java?

For example, I want to convert a String amount = $100.00 to an int.

I tried to use an `integer.parseInt();` but it is giving an error.

```
String Checkamount = $1400.00; //Convert web element to string.
int intAmount = Integer.parseInt(Checkamount);
```

Expected result: `1400.00`

### Error message

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "$1,400.00"
>           at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)

Comment: Your expected result of `1400.00` isn't an `int`.

Comment: You could start by calling `replaceAll` on the string, to remove the dollar sign.  Remember to escape the dollar sign from the regular expression parser (use `"\\$"`).  Also, I doubt whether you really want to use `int` - it looks like you're dealing with values that may contain non-whole amounts.

Comment: `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US).parse("$1,400.00").doubleValue()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Amount of money **must not** be stored in Integer.
- Amount of money **should** be stored in BigDecimal to keep accuracy. ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency/3730040#3730040))

To work with a currency string, you can use `NumberFormat` with `locale`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Locale locale = new Locale("en", "US");

    NumberFormat currencyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);

    try {
        String input = "$123,456,56.2";
        Number money = currencyFormat.parse(input);
        BigDecimal moneyAmount = BigDecimal.valueOf(money.doubleValue());
        //Do whatever you want with money amount here.
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
        pe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, `1400.00` can not be converted to `int` because it has decimal places.  You need to use the variable type `double` or `float` to store this value.

Use Java's `replace()` to replace out the unwanted characters before converting to a number.  Ex.

```
amount = amount.replace('$', '').replace(',', '');
double doubleAmount = Double.parseDouble(amount);
```

There's a cleaner way to do the replacement using a proper regex, but this should work.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I have tried this but it showing an error as below                     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1 415.00"
 at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2054)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
 at java.base/java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:461)
 at anzTesting.testing.login(testing.java:34)

Comment: @Antony `1 415.00` has a space in it instead of `,` - to get a better response, you need to be clear in your expected inputs (and outputs ;))

Comment: my sample code is here I using getting the input from my bank account using selenium web driver. [Sample code](https://codeshare.io/5XY1nE).

Comment: Make sure you are replacing the characters with empty characters, not spaces.  I think you might be using `' '` instead of `''`

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class DollarToInt{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException{
        //Method 1 --> ERROR WHEN \n incl
        String amount="$1,32423410.00"; 
        amount=amount.replace("$", "").replace(",", "");
        double toDouble= Double.parseDouble(amount);

        //Method 2 --> IGNORES \n
        String amount2 = "$1,2131000.00";
        DollarToInt method2= new DollarToInt();
        BigDecimal toBigDecimal=method2.parse(amount2, Locale.US);

        //Method 3 -> WHEN \n incl REMOVES VALUES RIGHT OF \n
        Double toDouble3= NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US).parse("$1, 400.00").doubleValue();

        System.out.println(toDouble); //M1
        System.out.println(toBigDecimal); //M2
        System.out.println(toDouble3); //M3
    }

     public BigDecimal parse(final String amount, final Locale locale) throws ParseException {
        final NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale);
        if (format instanceof DecimalFormat) {
            ((DecimalFormat) format).setParseBigDecimal(true);
        }
        return (BigDecimal) format.parse(amount.replaceAll("[^\\d.,]",""));
    }
}
```

I've tried two ways to parse the dollar format and I think method 2 works better and is the better way. 
Refer to : [Converting different countrys currency to double using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23990805/converting-different-countrys-currency-to-double-using-java)

Answer (score 0):

Use substring.

```
String value = amount.substring(1,amount.length());
```

the "value" will now only store the number without dollar sign.

```
 double doubleAmount = Double.parseDouble(value);
```

i think this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Here the thing  1400.00 can not be converted to int.
But if you want without decimal point then here is the complete solution

```
    String amount = "$1400.00";
    amount = amount.replace('$', ' ');
    int intAmount= (int)Double.parseDouble(amount);
```

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake, I was trying to convert to double. [This is the link for my sample code](https://codeshare.io/5XY1nE)

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to make use of `NumberFormat` - the only restriction to this is making sure you're using an appropriate `Locale`

For example...

```
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
try {
    Number number = formatter.parse("$1000.40");
    System.out.println(number);
    System.out.println(number.intValue());
    System.out.println(number.doubleValue());
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Will print

```
1000.4
1000
1000.4
```

You could also us an input of `$1,000.40` and it would give you the same results.

Again, the caveat here is, the `NumberFormatter` will expect the input to be the same as it's output.  For example, the above `NumberFormatter` will output a double value of `1000.6` as `$1,000.60`